# PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I am having this fatal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached
```

I saw some solution where it is advised to increase xdebug value in php.ini but I do not have any settings related to xdebug in my php.ini

Comment: so add this setting

Comment: [Base caaaaseeee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Short-circuiting_the_base_case)